# Supposed to have 256GB RAM, but system only shows 220GB

Tags: linux, memory, hardware, hp, hp-proliant

Have just added an extra Xeon quad core E5-2603v2 CPU to my HP DL360p Gen 8 and 16*16GB of ram. `free -g` however only shows 220GB:

```
# free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            220           4         214           0           1         215
Swap:             0           0           0
```

The modules are inserted according to the [HP quick spec page 54](https://www.hpe.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04123167.pdf).

`lshw` is below which confirms I have placed all 16 modules in order:

```
1 2 4 5 8 9 11 12
```

**Question**

So the big question is, why don't I have 256GB of ram, when `lshw` can see all modules and they are placed in correct order?

Link to `hpasmcli -s "SHOW DIMM"` output. http://pastebin.com/28mdQV2D

```
 *-memory:0
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 1000
      slot: System board or motherboard
    *-bank:0
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1866 MHz (0.5 ns)
         product: 712383-081
         vendor: HP
         physical id: 0
         slot: PROC  1 DIMM  1
         size: 16GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1866MHz (0.5ns)
    *-bank:1
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
         product: NOT AVAILABLE
         vendor: UNKNOWN
         physical id: 1
         slot: PROC  1 DIMM  2
         size: 16GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
    *-bank:2
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous [empty]
         product: NOT AVAILABLE
         vendor: UNKNOWN
         physical id: 2
         slot: PROC  1 DIMM  3
         width: 64 bits
    *-bank:3
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
         product: NOT AVAILABLE
         vendor: UNKNOWN
         physical id: 3
         slot: PROC  1 DIMM  4
         size: 16GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
    *-bank:4
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
         product: NOT AVAILABLE
         vendor: UNKNOWN
         physical id: 4
         slot: PROC  1 DIMM  5
         size: 16GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
    *-bank:5
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous [empty]
         product: NOT AVAILABLE
         vendor: UNKNOWN
         physical id: 5
         slot: PROC  1 DIMM  6
         width: 64 bits
    *-bank:6
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous [empty]
         product: NOT AVAILABLE
         vendor: UNKNOWN
         physical id: 6
         slot: PROC  1 DIMM  7
         width: 64 bits
    *-bank:7
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
         product: NOT AVAILABLE
         vendor: UNKNOWN
         physical id: 7
         slot: PROC  1 DIMM  8
         size: 16GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
    *-bank:8
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1866 MHz (0.5 ns)
         product: 712383-081
         vendor: HP
         physical id: 8
         slot: PROC  1 DIMM  9
         size: 16GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1866MHz (0.5ns)
    *-bank:9
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous [empty]
         product: NOT AVAILABLE
         vendor: UNKNOWN
         physical id: 9
         slot: PROC  1 DIMM 10
         width: 64 bits
    *-bank:10
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
         product: NOT AVAILABLE
         vendor: UNKNOWN
         physical id: a
         slot: PROC  1 DIMM 11
         size: 16GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
    *-bank:11
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1866 MHz (0.5 ns)
         product: 712383-081
         vendor: HP
         physical id: b
         slot: PROC  1 DIMM 12
         size: 16GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1866MHz (0.5ns)
 *-memory:1
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 1001
      slot: System board or motherboard
    *-bank:0
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1866 MHz (0.5 ns)
         product: 712383-081
         vendor: HP
         physical id: 0
         slot: PROC  2 DIMM  1
         size: 16GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1866MHz (0.5ns)
    *-bank:1
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
         product: NOT AVAILABLE
         vendor: UNKNOWN
         physical id: 1
         slot: PROC  2 DIMM  2
         size: 16GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
    *-bank:2
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous [empty]
         product: NOT AVAILABLE
         vendor: UNKNOWN
         physical id: 2
         slot: PROC  2 DIMM  3
         width: 64 bits
    *-bank:3
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
         product: NOT AVAILABLE
         vendor: UNKNOWN
         physical id: 3
         slot: PROC  2 DIMM  4
         size: 16GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
    *-bank:4
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
         product: NOT AVAILABLE
         vendor: UNKNOWN
         physical id: 4
         slot: PROC  2 DIMM  5
         size: 16GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
    *-bank:5
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous [empty]
         product: NOT AVAILABLE
         vendor: UNKNOWN
         physical id: 5
         slot: PROC  2 DIMM  6
         width: 64 bits
    *-bank:6
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous [empty]
         product: NOT AVAILABLE
         vendor: UNKNOWN
         physical id: 6
         slot: PROC  2 DIMM  7
         width: 64 bits
    *-bank:7
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
         product: NOT AVAILABLE
         vendor: UNKNOWN
         physical id: 7
         slot: PROC  2 DIMM  8
         size: 16GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
    *-bank:8
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1866 MHz (0.5 ns)
         product: 712383-081
         vendor: HP
         physical id: 8
         slot: PROC  2 DIMM  9
         size: 16GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1866MHz (0.5ns)
    *-bank:9
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous [empty]
         product: NOT AVAILABLE
         vendor: UNKNOWN
         physical id: 9
         slot: PROC  2 DIMM 10
         width: 64 bits
    *-bank:10
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
         product: NOT AVAILABLE
         vendor: UNKNOWN
         physical id: a
         slot: PROC  2 DIMM 11
         size: 16GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
    *-bank:11
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1866 MHz (0.5 ns)
         product: 712383-081
         vendor: HP
         physical id: b
         slot: PROC  2 DIMM 12
         size: 16GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1866MHz (0.5ns)
```

Comment: Type `hpasmcli -s "SHOW DIMM"`

Comment: @ewwhite Link to `hpasmcli -s "SHOW DIMM"` output. http://pastebin.com/28mdQV2D . There seams to be two modules not working. Is it ok to have 14 modules if I still follow the order in the quick spec?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the front panel of your HP ProLiant DL380 Gen9 server that features health status LEDs. If any of them are not green, you have a problem.

[image]

This shows your DIMMs and the health of the modules.

```
hpasmcli -s "SHOW DIMM"
```

This shows your system's Integrated Management Log and has a timestamped record of what's happened to the server.

```
hplog -v
```

Put these together to see the status of your server. If your DIMMs are not healthy, they should be reseated and re-tested, or replaced entirely under warranty. Your system is still under manufacturer warranty, so you can have these replaced in one business day.